# Django getting objects from a mixin

Tags: python, django

I have a small model method I'm using to get the previous and next object relative to the current object. It looks something like this:

```
class Article
    ...
    def get_prev_next(self):
        articles = list(Article.objects.all())
        i = articles.index(self)
        try:
            p = articles[i - 1]
        except IndexError:
            p = None
        try:
            n = articles[i + 1]
        except IndexError:
            n = None

        return {'prev': p, 'next': n}
```

It works, and may well be inefficient, but now I want to use it in a different model.

I'd like to make this into a mixin, but I can't figure out how to get the original model class name so I can run Model.objects.all() and get my list.

I have so far:

```
class PrevNextMixin(object):
    objects = list(???.objects.all())
    i = objects.index(self)
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mixin is still a class. The code still needs to go into a method. That method will get a `self` argument just as it does now.

```
class PrevNextMixin(object):
    def get_prev_next(self):
        objects = list(self.__class__.objects.all())
```

Comment: I'm aware it needs to go in a method, just hasty typing on my part. The self.__class__ is what wasn't coming to my brain. Thanks!